# Kubuntu NVIDIA Proprietary Driver forcing 100fps on 60Hz monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

y'all. I decided to get the proprietary NVIDIA drivers on Kubuntu via the "Additional Drivers" menu because I've heard that it increases performance over Noveau. I have a GTX 1050 Ti. I installed them and the loading animations on the icons were SUPER fast. The scrolling in Firefox was also really weird. I checked the FPS using the built-in KDE Plasma feature and it claimed my FPS was 100FPS. On Noveau, it claimed 60. Important to note: My laptop has a 60Hz monitor, so the NVIDIA drivers must be causing some weird FPS bug. I looked in NVIDIA X Server Settings but no options helped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 100FPS in a 60Hz monitor shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It does cause a problem. The scrolling looks choppy and the loading animations are really fast.

Comment: Screen tearing is unrelated with what you're thinking. I suggest trying this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1263571/1210606

Comment: Here is a possible solution using `xrandr`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/433855/how-to-make-custom-refresh-rate-stay-saved