# How to set custom video refresh rate higher than only 30 Hz or 44 Hz with Xrandr? Nvidia + HDMI 1.4 on UWQHD display (3440x1440)

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, hdmi, screen, external-monitor

tl;dr

I edited my question and added this part when I found out that I was on the right way and the remaining question now is how to use Xrandr to set a refresh rate of 50 Hz (VESA compatible) and 56 Hz (maximum of HDMI 1.4) instead of only 44 Hz which seems to be the maximum that Xrandr allows with this modeline from cvt:

```
"3440x1440_44.00"  299.75  3440 3664 4024 4608  1440 1443 1453 1479 -hsync +vsync
```

I guess it's the numbers. 56 Hz and 50 Hz do work with the same devices under Windows with a tool called "Custom Resolution Utility", but this tool is calculating 56 Hz with a pixel clock of 298.57 MHz. The pixel clock for 44 Hz calculated by cvt is higher and the ones it calculates for 50 or 56 Hz are way above.

The working settings with the CRU tool are:

```
Active: 3440 pixels 1440 lines
Front porch: 48 pixels 3 lines
Sync width: 32 pixels 10 lines
Back porch: 80 pixels 28 lines
Blanking: 160 pixels 41 lines
Total: 3600 pixels 1481 lines
Sync polarity: H + / V -

Refresh rate: 56.000 Hz Actual 56.000 Hz
Horizontal: 82.936 kHz Actual 82.936 kHz
Pixel clock: 298.57 MHz

Refresh rate: 50.000 Hz Actual 50.000 Hz
Horizontal: 74.050 kHz Actual 74.050 kHz
Pixel clock: 266.58 MHz
```

Is this possible to translate to 2 modelines (for 56 Hz and 50 Hz)?

The long story:

I got a new 3440x1440 monitor and tragically discovered that it gets only 30 Hz in full resolution from my Asus F/X571 laptop with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 graphics on Ubuntu 22.04, currently using X server and Nvidia driver 535.113.01. This laptop has dual graphics with Intel but is set to Nvidia mode.

The monitor supports up to 100 Hz at 3440x1440 on USB-C, DisplayPort and HDMI 2.0. The laptop however only has HDMI 1.4 which limits the maximum refresh rate at 3440x1440 to 56.048 Hz. ([Source](https://superuser.com/questions/1355763/maximum-refresh-rate-with-hdmi-1-4-and-3440x1440-resolution))

I want to change the refresh rate in Ubuntu to 50 Hz or 56 Hz, which would be quite okay to work which 30 Hz is not. But all methods I found in various old and recent posts fail.

- Change refresh rate in Nvidia Settings (as shown [here](https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2017/09/15/how-to-set-the-default-monitor-refresh-rate/)) is not possible because I don't have the resolution and refresh rate input fields. It says "PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings and must be configured by an external RandR capable tool." When I select X screen settings, I can change the Virtual Size but there is no field for refresh rate.
- Simply setting the desired refresh rate with xrandr, which was the favorite solution for many people [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433855/how-to-make-custom-refresh-rate-stay-saved), has no effect:

  xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 3440x1440 --rate 50
- The second best solution from the same thread suggested to edit ~/.config/monitors.xml – this file exists on my system, however it has no entry for my current monitor. (It was last modified in March 2020…)
- Very old threads like [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/changing-screen-resolution-and-frequency-with-nvidia-settings-from-the-cli-545963/) suggested to edit xorg.conf, but that method seems to be out of date. xorg.conf as is does not seem to exist any more.
- And of course I tried to create a new modeline with cvt, add it to my available modes with xrandr and then activate it with xandr, but it does not work: The screen goes blank for about 2 seconds, then reverts to 30 Hz. Afaik, I should also be able to see the new mode in System Settings GUI and choose it there but there is only the default 3440x1440 mode.

Here is my result of xrandr -q and the error message when trying to activate. I left out the data from the internal screen eDP-1-1 because it is always deactivated when I use this monitor.

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-1-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
   3440x1440     29.99* 
   2560x1080     59.98    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1720x1440     59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      99.97    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       99.99    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480      100.00    75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   3440x1440_50.00  49.96
  3440x1440_50.00 (0x267) 344.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3440 start 3672 end 4040 total 4640 skew    0 clock  74.14KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1453 total 1484           clock  49.96Hz

$ xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode "3440x1440_50.00" --verbose 
crtc 0: 3440x1440_50.00  49.96 +0+0 "HDMI-1-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
```

I am out of ideas now and can't find any other advices. What can I do?

Could I, instead of adding a new "3440x1440_50.00" mode, just add the refresh rate(s) to the existing "3440x1440" mode so the system would automatically select the highest rate?

Comment: I've asked ChatGPT tp create a modeline for the 56 Hz mode from CRU and it gave me this, which strangely results in a refresh rate of 49 Hz, as reported by the monitor: 

xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_56.00" 298.57 3440 3600 3760 3920 1440 1481 1522 1563 +HSync +VSync

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the 10 years old command line tool [umc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umc/) (Universal Modeline Calculator) which is able to calculate modelines with Reduced Blanking Timing for 3440x1440 @ 56 Hz:

```
"3440x1440x55.97"  298.000000  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1447 1479  +HSync -VSync
```

as close as it can get to 56 Hz, or

```
"3440x1440x56.34"  300.000000  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1447 1479  +HSync -VSync
```

whis probably is the possible maximum, as a pixel clock greater than 300 MHz will not work.